# Matlab: mix-up of built-in and external functions

Tags: matlab

Matlab (2015a) is behaving weirdly: a number of builtin functions are not responding as expected. For instance, typing

```
ttest([1 2], [1 2])
```

results in

```
Error using size
Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.

Error in nanstd (line 59)
tile(dim) = size(x,dim);

Error in ttest (line 132)
sdpop = nanstd(x,[],dim);
```

If I do a which for each of these functions:

```
which size
which nanstd
which ttest
```

I get, respetively:

```
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\matlab\elmat\size)
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\stats\eml\nanstd.m
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\stats\stats\ttest.m
```

Each of these files looks fine, except that size.m has each one of its rows commented out.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I have the answer as NaN on 2015b

Comment: `size` is a MATLAB built-in, there is no publicly viewable code. What you are seeing is the inline documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I clearly chose the wrong 'hello world' example - ttest([1 2], [3 4]) would have been better, as it gives the above error message without stumbling into the NaN problem. Anyway, I replaced the wrongly-addressed 'size', but the mix-up of built-in function still persists. For instance, if I type clc, I am just returned to the command prompt, and if I do a which clc -all I get:

Comment: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\matlab\connector\connector\jsd_lcl_nmw\shadow\clc.p

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\matlab\connector\connector\jsd_rmt_nmw\shadow\clc.p  % Shadowed

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\matlab\connector\connector\web_common\shadow\clc.p   % Shadowed

built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\matlab\iofun\clc)                          % Shadowed

Comment: What do you specifically mean by, "returned to the command prompt"?

Comment: I mean nothing at all happens, i.e. the cursor returns to the >> command prompt, and the command window is not cleared

Comment: @longtalker See my updated answer. Have you recently upgraded your version of Matlab from an extremely old version? Did you have a failed/incomplete install?

Comment: I did not have a failed/incomplete install but I did install 2015a over an existing 2013b that had a different licence. The two versions exist separately under c:\Program Files\MATLAB\, and the mix-ups indicated by the which command that I report elsewhere in this thread all point to files within the current version (2015a) rather than mix-ups with the older version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Perhaps related to your problem:

`ttest` for R2013a makes the following call:

```
sdpop = nanstd(x,[],dim);
```

The helpfile for R2013a version of `nanstd` states:

```
Y = nanstd(X,FLAG,DIM) takes the standard deviation along dimension DIM of X.
```

On the other hand, `nanstd` in the 2005 `nansuite` package [downloaded off Mathworks file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6837-nan-suite/content/nansuite/nanstd.m) states:

```
  FORMAT: Y = nanstd(X,DIM,FLAG)
```

*Notice how DIM and FLAG are reversed!*

If I call R2013a's `ttest` such that it makes a call to the old, 2005 nansuite function `nanstd`, Matlab generates an error similar to yours:

```
Error using size
Dimension argument must be a positive integer scalar within indexing range.

Error in nanmean (line 46)
count = size(x,dim) - sum(nans,dim);

Error in nanstd (line 54)
avg = nanmean(x,dim);

Error in ttest (line 132)
sdpop = nanstd(x,[],dim);
```

If `[]` is passed as DIM instead of FLAG, then nanstd's call to `size(x, DIM)` triggers an error because `[]` is not a positive integer scalar. If something like this is the cause, the broader question is, what's going on with your Matlab install or setup or downloads or whatever such that you're calling archaic code? Or why is that archaic code even around? I don't know at what point in Matlab's release history that `nanstd(x, FLAG, DIM)` became supported (instead of simply `nanstd(x, DIM)`)?

#### Archive: below is my old answer which misdiagnosed your problem

Both of your sample vectors `x` and `y` are the same (i.e. `[1,2]`). The estimated variance of the difference is 0, and all your stats are going to blow up with `NaN`.

Do the stats step by step, and it will be clear what's going on.

```
x = [1; 2];  % Data you used in the example.
y = [1; 2];  % Data you used in the example.
z = x - y;   % Your call to ttest tests whether this vector is different from zero at a statistically significant level.
```

Now we do all the stats on z

```
r.n  = length(z);
r.mu = mean(z);
r.standard_error = sqrt(var(z,1) / (r.n-1));    % For your data, this will be zero since z is constant!
r.t = r.mu ./ r.standard_error;              % For your data, this will be inf because dividing by zero!
r.df = r.n - 1;
r.pvals(r.t >= 0) = 2 * (1 - tcdf(r.t(r.t>=0), r.df));  % For your data, tcdf returns NaN and this all fails...
r.pvals(r.t < 0)  = 2 * tcdf(r.t(r.t<0), r.df);
```

etc...

This should match a call to 
    `[h, p, ci, stats] = ttest(x-y);`

Comment: Hi Matthew, might my comments to the previous answer make sense in light of your own answer? Still havent been able to fix Matlab, despite the suggestions I received..

Comment: Can you a post a link to the comment, header section of `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\stats\eml\nanstd.m?`

Comment: @longtalker So your error refers to, "Error in nanstd (line 59)
tile(dim) = size(x,dim);" but this doesn't have a line 59. Do you have another nanstd floating around somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so, since the command ">> which nanstd -all" returns "
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\toolbox\stats\stats\nanstd.m ". But what is more puzzling is the clc symptom, as there the built-in file is shadowed by three .P files, located under R2015a\toolbox\matlab\connector\connector\ , and I'm not sure how to make all these connections straight again

Comment: @longtalker If the error you're receiving is, "Error in nanstd (line 59)
tile(dim) = size(x,dim);" then somewhere, there is nanstd code that's failing on line 59. That *can't* be the code you just linked to in paste-bin... it's got to be executing something else.

Comment: @longtalker Frankly, I'd move everything to an archive directory and reinstall. If that doesn't work, you have to contact Matlab tech support.

Comment: Many thanks again Matthew for your help. Just for the record, the only temporary workaround that actually did help wth this is using the command restoredefaultpath, although the problem comes back upon each restart of matlab